# NSDateFormatter Locale

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

How to set Locale for NSDateFormatter? I've tried the below code and its not working.

```
- (NSString *)localizedStringWithFormat:(NSString *)format {

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:format];
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"fr_FR"];
    cal.locale = locale;
    df.calendar = cal;
    return [df stringFromDate:self];
}
```

Please let me know how to make this work.

Thanks.

Comment: I just set the date formatter's locale directly.  I'd have to check for sure, but your scheme may be setting the locale for *every* user of currentCalendar.  (Not obvious why it wouldn't be working otherwise.)

Comment: By the way, what makes you say it's not working?

Comment: It would be nice to add your expect result to your question. And or what result you are receiving that makes you think it's not working. Remember the date/time that is displayed in Xcode NSLog is GMT.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] 
                     initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks. Can you please tell me what does "he" donotes?

Comment: Got it "he" mean Hebrew.

Answer (score 5):

in case someone will look for **Swift 3** solution:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let frLocale = Locale(identifier: "fr")
dateFormatter.locale = frLocale
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but this is what I did in Swift today:

```
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
df.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
df.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
println("Date: \(df.stringFromDate(obj.dateSent!))")
```

Depending on your OS region settings, the output should look like this (I'm in Germany):

```
Date: 27.11.2014 12:30:39
```

Note: Just figured a lot more people stumble across this SO question, so I guess it can't hurt to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this as I spent some time on trying to NOT use the localized locale in my date formatter.

From apple docs:
Use the system locale **when you don’t want any localizations**. Use the current locale to format text that you display to users.

Code: [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];