# iOS time in 24 hours format

Tags: ios, date, time, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to get the current time and parse it to an `String` in `24 hours` format, for example `13:30`.

This is my code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

It works on the `iOS simulator`, but on my `iPad` I get `3:30 PM`.

I have played around with different `formats` but still the same result.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the user's local is set to a 12 hour format. Set the local to `en_US_POSIX` to over-ride the user's setting.

```
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

Comment: Thanks @zaph it works. I've changed your answer to `formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];` regarding @neuhaus answer and it also works

Comment: Exactly, this known bug is [described by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html): "The representation of the time may be 13:00. In iOS, however, if the user has switched 24-Hour Time to Off, the time may be 1:00 pm.".

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set the locale to one with a 24 hour time.

See [NSDateFormatter Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964747/nsdateformatter-locale) for details on how to set the locale for the `NSDateFormatter`.

Note the answer by @mtb to that question. It explains how to not use a locale.